# setting sensor port permissions

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working with different sensors that all require I run things like:

$ sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0

$ sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0

to set the port permissions before ROS can see the sensor data. I would like to set these permanently (or somehow in a config or launch file) so I don't need to manually process this step with each attempt to run my app.

Please advise.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195382/setting-sensor-port-permissions/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2014-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add yourself to the dialout group using `sudo adduser MyUser dialout` and log out.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2014-10-20**:
Thanks Tony!!

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2014-10-20**:
The answer works because those devices you listed are owned by the `dialout` group. The more general way to do this is with `udev` rules. See this page: http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#ownership